# HTML option form with php

Tags: php, html

Currently I'm a bit stuck on PHP and HTML, my teacher has asked me to change my code into a drop down selection,

So far i have this

```
$html .='<option value="Argentina" <?php if($_POST['YourCountry']=="Argentina") echo "selected=selected"; ?>>Argentina</option>';
```

I'm not sure why it isn't working. I'm trying to get it so that when a person selects the option in the box it will be the value set into the insert query. This was my input one which my teacher ask me to change into a option one i have no idea how the option one

```
$html .='<input type="text" name="userCountry" id="userCountry" value="'.htmlentities(stripcslashes($_POST['userCountry'])).'" /><br/>'."\n";
```

Full code ===================================>

```
<?php

class HomeView extends View {
    protected function displayContent() {
        $html .= '<div id="pageinfo">'."\n";
        $html .= '<h2>'.$this -> pageInfo['pageHeading'].'</h2>'."\n";
        $html .= '</div>'."\n";
            if($_POST['register'] == "Submit") {
            //validate the form



            $vresult = $this -> model -> validateRegisterUser();


            //Check ALL okay
                 if ($vresult['ok'] == true) {
                //Call database


                            if ($this -> model -> register()) {
                                $htmt .='<div id="space">'."\n";
                                $html .='<div id="userreg">'."\n";
                                $html .='<p> User registered successfully<p>'."\n";
                                $html .= '<p>Please login '.$_POST['userName'].'</p>'."\n";
                                $html .='<img src ="optimized/images/joined.jpg" alt="welcome new member"/>'."\n";

                                $html .='</div>'."\n";
                                $html .='</div>'."\n";
                                    } else {

                                $html .='<div id="space">'."\n";
                                $html .='<img src ="optimized/images/failed.jpg" alt="failed to create new member"/>'."\n";
                                $html .= '<p> User creation failed. Please try again <p>'."\n";
                                $html .='</div>'."\n";
                            }        
                        return $html;
                }   
            }
            $html .='<div id="register">'."\n";

                $html .='<img src="optimized/images/rg.jpg" alt="registerimage"/>'."\n";
                $html .='<form method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" onSubmit="return confirm("Are you sure?");">'."\n";
                    $html .='<fieldset>'."\n";
                        $html .='<legend>'.'New Members Form'.'</legend>'."\n";
                        $html .='<label for="username">Username: </label><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" value="'.htmlentities(stripcslashes($_POST['userName'])).'" /><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<div class="error">'.$vresult['userNameMsg'].'</div>'."\n";
                        $html .='<label for="userFName">Firstname: </label><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<input type="text" name="userFName" id="userFName1" value="'.htmlentities(stripcslashes($_POST['userFName'])).'" /><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<div class="error">'.$vresult['userFNameMsg'].'</div>'."\n";
                        $html .='<label for="userLName">Surname: </label><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<input type="text" name="userLName" id="userLName" value="'.htmlentities(stripcslashes($_POST['userLName'])).'" /><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<div class="error">'.$vresult['userLNameMsg'].'</div>'."\n";
                        $html .='<label for="userEmail">Email: </label><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<input type="text" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" value="'.htmlentities(stripcslashes($_POST['userEmail'])).'" /><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<div class="error">'.$vresult['userEmailMsg'].'</div>'."\n";
                        $html .='<label for="userPassword">Password: </label><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<input type="password" name="userPassword" id="userPassword1" value="'.htmlentities(stripcslashes($_POST['userPassword'])).'" /><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<div class="error">'.$vresult['userPasswordMsg'].'</div>'."\n";
                        $html .='<label for="userPassword">Re-Enter Password: </label><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<input type="password" name="userPassword2" id="userPassword2" value="'.htmlentities(stripcslashes($_POST['userPassword2'])).'" /><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<div class="error">'.$vresult['userPrematchPass'].'</div>'."\n";



                        $html .='<label for="userPhone">Telephone: </label><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<input type="text" name="userPhone" id="userPhone" value="'.htmlentities(stripcslashes($_POST['userPhone'])).'" /><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<div class="error">'.$vresult['userPhoneMsg'].'</div>'."\n";
                        $html .='<label for="userAddress">Address: </label><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<input type="text" name="userAddress" id="userAddress" value="'.htmlentities(stripcslashes($_POST['userAddress'])).'" /><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<div class="error">'.$vresult['userAddressMsg'].'</div>'."\n";
                        $html .='<label for="userCity">City: </label><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<input type="text" name="userCity" id="userCity" value="'.htmlentities(stripcslashes($_POST['userCity'])).'" /><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<div class="error">'.$vresult['userCityMsg'].'</div>'."\n";
                        $html .='<label for="userCountry">NewZealand: </label><br/>'."\n";
                         $html .='<select name="Location">'."\n";
$html .='<option value=""></option>'."\n";
$html .='<option value="North-Island">North-Island</option>';
$html .='<option value="South-Island">South-Island</option>';
$html .='<option value="Other">Other</option>';
 $html .='<option value="Argentina" <?php if($_POST['YourCountry']=="Argentina") echo "selected=selected"; ?>>Argentina</option>';








                        $html .='<input type="text" name="userCountry" id="userCountry" value="'.htmlentities(stripcslashes($_POST['userCountry'])).'" /><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<div class="error">'.$vresult['userCountryMsg'].'</div>'."\n";
                        $html .='<label for="userPostcode">Post Code: </label><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<input type="text" name="userPostcode" id="userPostcode" value="'.htmlentities(stripcslashes($_POST['userPostcode'])).'" /><br/>'."\n";
                        $html .='<div class="error">'.$vresult['userPostcodeMsg'].'</div>'."\n";
                        $html .='<input type="submit" name="register" value="Submit" id="submit"/>'."\n";
                    $html .='</fieldset>'."\n";
                $html .='</form>'."\n";
            $html .=' </div>'."\n";
        return $html;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You need to use `<select>` and have multiple options to iterate over

Comment: It is likely that your teacher gave you a handout or a book. Why not looking there?

Comment: can u show me on text? or example please not sure what i mean

Answer (score 0):

ADD

```
</select>
```

ADD

```
<?php if($_POST['YourCountry']=="XXXXX") echo "selected=selected"; ?>
```

in other option tag

change

```
<select name="Location"> to  <select name="YourCountry">
```

**

```
action="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'"  is not good for Xss
```